# prime number problem:

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How can I show that;

> For any prime $p,$ there exist $u, v\in\mathbb{N}\setminus{\{p\}}$  ( and depend on $p$) such that $\color{Purple}{p\mid uv}$ and both $$\color{Green}{\dfrac{u^2+p^2}{\dfrac{uv}{p}-p}}\,\,\,\,\,\text{,}\,\,\,\,\,\color{Red}{\dfrac{v^2+p^2}{\dfrac{uv}{p}-p}}\,\,\,\,\,\text{are integers.}$$

I have no idea to attempt this question. Any idea, hint or explanation would be appreciate.
Thank you.

Comment: @ZevChonoles: no, the parenthesized term in the denominator is $p$, so the denominator is zero.

Comment: Ha ha. Thank You. I missed that. I should add that $u, v\not= p$

Comment: @Ross: I interpreted it as a Legendre symbol. Nilan, could you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u=p, v = p+1$ work. I was just playing with it, so no constructive hint how to tackle this other than the obvious one that $u$ or $v$ or both need $p$ as a factor.

Edit: you added the constraint $u, v \ne p$. Then $u=2p, v= 3p$ work. If you try to make both the numerators and the denominator multiples of $p$, in the form denominator $ip$, numerator $ki p^2$, it's arguably the second natural attempt (after declining (2,2) as powers).

Answer (score 2):

Take any two integers $m,n$ such that $mn-1 | p$ then $u=mp, v=np$ will work.